# How to CREATE TABLE ... LIKE without the NOT NULL Constraints?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying recreate a table's structure inside a function by using some dynamic SQL.

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || my_table_name || '_bk' ||
    ' (like ' || _my_table_name || ')';
```

That will be similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_bk
(like my_table);
```

But I need to discard all constraints. Using `EXCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` in the [Like Options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtable.html), it still copy the NOT NULL Constraints (Documentation confirms this behavior):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_bk
(like my_table EXCLUDING CONSTRAINTS);
```

The question is, how can I recreate the table structure without the NOT NULL constraints, or, in alternative, remove all NOT NULL constraints in a table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was asked on Stack Overflow in [How to drop all NOT NULL constraints from a PostgreSQL table in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146475/how-to-drop-all-not-null-constraints-from-a-postgresql-table-in-one-go). It appears to give a good range of solutions.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146537) by [Denis de Bernardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417194/denis-de-bernardy) is:

> You can group them all in the same alter statement:
>
> ```
>    alter table tbl alter col1 drop not null,
>                    alter col2 drop not null,
>                    …
> ```
>
> You can also retrieve the list of relevant columns from the catalog, if you feel like writing a [do block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) to generate the needed SQL. For instance, something like:
>
> ```
> select a.attname
>   from pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
>  where attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
>    and a.attnum > 0
>    and not a.attisdropped
>    and a.attnotnull;
> ```
>
> (Note that this will include the primary key-related fields too, so you'll want to filter those out.)
>
> If you do this, don't forget to use `quote_ident()` in the event you ever need to deal with potentially weird characters in column names.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_bk
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE false;
```

Or, you can append `LIMIT 0` instead of the `WHERE` clause.

This will create a table `my_table_bk` with the same structure as `my_table` without constraints and without data.

Comment: This is definitely cleaner than accepted answer for the OP's use case; about the only advantage that the accepted has is that it still allows using the `create table .. (like ..)` and potentially `INCLUDING` other options. Otherwise this seems preferable.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this and add additional columns to the new table? Obviously can just do an `ALTER TABLE` and add the columns right after, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: [this method is better if you want to duplicate the table structure without constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84740/2639)**

I think the easiest way to create a table like without `NOT NULL` constraints, is to use a simple `pg_dump` and `sed`

```
pg_dump -Ox --schema-only -t myTable myDatabase |
  sed -ne'/^CREATE TABLE/,/);/p' -e's/^NOT NULL//';
```

You can easily expand this method to nuke out the rest of the constraints. That term is kind of broad, so I'm not sure what constraints you're not wanting.

### Options

The options can be found with `pg-dump --help`,

```
-O, --no-owner         skip restoration of object ownership in
-x, --no-privileges    do not dump privileges (grant/revoke)
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of using sed (and even awk - if I can ever master it!) for this kind of task - it's relatively easy to construct nice pipelines. Just as a matter of interest, what does the `-0x` parameter do with pg_dump? (+1)!

Comment: @Vérace updated